# Remove logging of current task in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a way to configure Grunt via its API or CLI tool to make it run quietly and stop polluting my console with information about every single task that runs?  I've looked through the documentation and Googled extensively but can't find anything.

Comment: You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-verbosity